# html/css custom checkbox span only trigger on click instead of outside the box

Tags: html, css

I have a custom checkbox which triggers outside of the box when I click on the page in a special area so like a few px around the box in a line. how can I fix it that its only triggers in the box on click?

html:

```
 <label class="container">
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="publish" checked="checked">
 <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
```

css:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
                        visibility: hidden;
                        }
                        .checkmark {
                          position: fixed;
                          margin-top: -6px;
                          margin-left: 500px;
                          height: 25px;
                          width: 25px;
                        }
                        .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
                          background-color: #ccc;
                        }
                        .container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
                          background-color: #5865F2;
                        }
                        .checkmark:after {
                          content: "";
                          position: absolute;
                          display: none;
                        }
                        .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
                          display: block;
                        }
                        .container .checkmark:after {
                          left: 9px;
                          top: 5px;
                          width: 5px;
                          height: 10px;
                          border: solid white;
                          border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
                          -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                          -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
                          transform: rotate(45deg);
                        }
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to receive, and we will definitely help you.

Comment: Or show the problem in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working correctly now.

```html
<label class="container">
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="publish" checked="checked">
 <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
 <style>
input[type=checkbox] {
                        visibility: hidden;
                        }
                        .checkmark {
                          position: fixed;
                                     border: 2px solid black;
               margin-top: -6px;
                          margin-left: 500px;
                          height: 25px;
                          width: 25px;
                        }
                        .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
                          background-color: #ccc;
                        }
                        .container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
                          background-color: #5865F2;
                        }
                        .checkmark:after {
                          content: "";
                          position: absolute;
                          border: 2px solid black;
                          display: none;
                        }
                        .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
                          display: block;
                        }
                        .container .checkmark:after {
                          left: 9px;
                          border: 2px solid black;
                          top: 5px;
                          width: 5px;
                          height: 10px;
                          border: solid white;
                          border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
                          -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                          -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
                          transform: rotate(45deg);
                        }
</style>
```